# x-blackberry-focusable being ignored on playbook

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

I'm working on an HTML5 app with webworks on a BlackBerry PlayBook.  I have a bunch of a href tags through out the site, some added at design time, and some generated dynamically.  When I load the app onto my device, I am getting into these strange situations where images wrapped in a href tags seem to get into a 'highlighted' state.  I'm seeing the same behavior for html buttons.  I also get into situations where things that should take a single tap seem to require two taps.  My assumption is this is caused by href / iframe / button elements getting focus:

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.focus.html

I programmatically add x-blackberry-focusable="false" to all of my a href tags, buttons, and iframes, but I still get that that blue highlight, and it still seems to take two taps to get anything to work.  This app works great with PhoneGap on the iPad, and works great in the browser.  I am starting to think I'm on the wrong track since I do not have focusable configured in config.xml.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Playbook has no trackball or trackpad, the x-blackberry-focusable attribute is ignored. This limitation has been clarified in the [updated documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.focus.html):

> **If the BlackBerry device doesn't have a trackball or trackpad**, the
>   focus-based navigation mode will not be enabled even if the widget
>   configuration document specifies that focus-based navigation is used.
>   If the widget is configured for focus-based navigation and it runs on
>   a BlackBerry device that uses a trackpad or trackball, focus-based
>   navigation will be enabled.
>
> In summary, running a widget with focus-based navigation mode markup
>   on a BlackBerry device without a trackball is the same as running the
>   widget without specifying any focus-based navigation and **the entire
>   navigation related HTML mark-up, JavaScript and CSS extensions are
>   ignored.**